# Is this a collectable bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Would appreciate any help in trying to identify this bicycle. HRSBO 71091[image]

Comment: More info would help us to help you. What country is this in? Where / how did you get it? Do you have any other info on it's previous owners / uses? Do you have any idea of it's age?

Comment: This bicycle is located in the United States and was found in the State of Delaware.Not aware of any previous use or ownership.Looks to have been manufactured before 1990.

Comment: It is unusual.  Appears to be designed as a semi-folding bike.  But the front brake looks a lot like a V-brake, which, if true (and original to the bike), would make it later than about 1995, from what I can find.  Looks like its been repainted.

Comment: Three speed hub shift mechanism is a Nexus.Front tire is 20" and rear tire is 24".

Comment: Whats the grey metal box on the seat tube?

Answer (score 5):

That looks a lot like the bikes in some bike-sharing programs (take a look at [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aStockholm-City-Bikes.JPG), from Stockholm City Bikes). The two "prongs" at the end of the front "basket" would be used to lock the bike in place at one of the stations. The panels in the back are often used for advertising.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite consistent.  The bike is inexpensively made but rugged -- styled after a standard kid's bike only longer frame.  The seatpost clamp is designed to be easily adjustable (yet likely prevents the seat from being easily removed).  And it looks like it was repainted to conceal it's original bright color (and the associated theft).